# Why do i get ConnectionResetError 10054 error?

Tags: python, long-polling, vk

I am writing a simply python script for vkontakte.com (vk.com). It's main task is to run constantly in background, tracking one exact group chat. When it comes to a new message in chat, script answers back on special keywords. Nothing hard. I am kinda new to python and it's connection architecture. After a random time script fails due ConnectionResetError when it comes to answer back with vk.messages.send() function. Fails completly random - might work for 9 minutes or 20 minutes, most of time fails during message send, but also fails if i leave script working for 20+ minutes time. What do i do now ? I need it to work constantly. Also i want to understand why connection fails.

main loop that tracks new messages is written like this:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
  if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
```

traceback of error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
        line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read                                               17:58
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение (remote peer forcing a connection to close)
```

continue of traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
        line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

and last one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vsk_bot.py", line 37, in <module>
vk.messages.send(
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 671, in __call__
return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 602, in method
values
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 581, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```